# Call a class function from within a child class

Tags: c++, class

Suppose an object of class B is a member of class A.

```
class B{
    //Definitions
}

class A{
public:
    A();
    B b_child;
    int some_function();
}
```

One of the functions defined inside `B` needs to call a (public) function from its owner (parent?) `A`. Is there an immediate way to do this?

The only way I've managed to do this so far was to implement it outside the classes' definitions:

```
A a_obj;
a_obj.b_child.setowner(&aobj);
```

which tells `b_child` who is its owner. I don't like this. I'd rather use some builtin method for `b_child` to access its parent (if possible). If that's not possible, I'd rather pass the owner's address directly in the constructor for `B`, but I don't know how to reference `A`'s address inside its definition.

Comment: It's a good question, although you should know that a "child class" has a very specific meaning in C++, related to inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin method to get the 'owner' of a variable, whatever that means. Your approach of setting the owner is correct. Furthermore, doing so in the construction of B is also a correct decision. Sample code:

```
class B
{
public:
    explicit B( A* owner ) : _owner( owner ) {}

    ...
private:
    A* _owner;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() : _child( this ) {}

    ...
private:
    B _child;
};
```

Note some compilers may give you a warning for using `this` in that context, but its ok for the current example. Just make sure you don't call any `A` member functions from within `B` constructor, since the pointer you get still points to an unconstructed object at that stage.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd rather use some builtin method for b_child to access its parent (if possible).

No, it's not.

> but I don't know how to reference A's address inside its definition.

You can use `this` pointer.

```
A() : b_child(this) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` pointer to refer to the object within itself

```
class B{
    //Definitions
}

class A{
private:
    B b_child;
public:
    A()
    { 
       b_child.set_owner(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define `B` like the following:

```
template <class T, int N>
class B
{
public:
  int example_func() { return static_cast<T&>(*this).some_function(); }
};
```

And then make `B<A>` a subclass of `A` (so it can call `A` directly).

```
class A : protected B<A,0>, protected B<A,1>
{
    A();
    int some_function() { return 42; }
};
```

This is called the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

If you don't want `B` to be a template class, and you're only going to use `B` with `A`, then the following is fine:

```
template <int N>
class B
{
public:
  int example_func() { return static_cast<A&>(*this).some_function(); }
};

class A : protected B<0>, protected B<1>
{
    A();
    int some_function() { return 42; }
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `B` with not just `A`, but don't want to make `B` a template class (say, if you want a collection of pointers to `B`), you can do the following:

```
template <int N>
class B
{
public:
  int example_func() { return some_function(); }
  virtual int some_function() = 0;
};

class A : protected B<0>, protected B<1>
{
    A();
    int some_function() { return 42; }
};
```

This will resolve the `some_function()` call at run-time, and require a virtual pointer to be stored in your class.

Comment: Is there an advantage compared to the method in the other answers?

Comment: You save a pointer, as there is no need to store a pointer to A in B as B is part of A (and therefore has the same address).

Comment: Ok, it took me a while, but I think I can't use these options. Though I didn't specify in the question, I need A to contain several objects of class B (each with independent parameters and variables). I understand this code correctly, that is not possible. Still, nice to know.